# Running pivot_longer() while knit Rmd always reports an error

Tags: r, r-markdown

I wrote a very simple R code and it also works fine when I run R-chunks direct in Rmd.

```
library(tidyr)
AirPassengers <- AirPassengers %>% 
  pivot_longer(-year, names_to = "month", values_to = "passengers")
```

But as soon as I try to knit this Rmd file, the following error is reported.  Why is this and what does it mean to report an error?

```
Error in UseMethod("pivot_longer") : 
  no applicable method for 'pivot_longer' applied to an object of class "list"
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> %>% -> pivot_longer
In addition: Warning messages:
1: replacing previous import 'lifecycle::last_warnings' by 'rlang::last_warnings' when loading 'pillar' 
2: replacing previous import 'lifecycle::last_warnings' by 'rlang::last_warnings' when loading 'tibble' 
3: package 'pammtools' was built under R version 4.0.5 
4: In AirPassengers$year <- as.numeric(rownames(AirPassengers)) :
  Coercing LHS to a list
Execution halted
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I googled and didn't find any useful answers.
I'm curious why it works fine in the current chunk and gets the desired result but not in knit.
Also: the line referred to in the error report is only the code to load the package tidyr.

Comment: You very likely did something outside of the Rmd document to the `AirPassengers` object. When knit, a Rmd document runs the code in a fresh R session, and not in the R session you currently have going. A quick way to check any difference in the object would be to comment out your `pivot_longer()` line and add `str(AirPassengers)`. Run that command in the console and knit the Rmd. Do you see a difference between the two outputs?

Comment: It might be because AirPassengers isn't a dataframe or a tibble, it's a [`ts` object](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/datasets/html/AirPassengers.html).

Comment: The thing about knitting is it starts from a fresh R environment.  I suspect you've been editing your Rmd file interactively and produced an object AirPassengers that's different from the one that's created by running the Rmd from start to finish.  Recommend you clear your environment, restart R, and run the notebook again in your IDE to help debug.

Comment: @jrcalabrese It is possible that OP has their own dataset that they happened to give that name. Using `pivot_longer()` on the default dataset wouldn't work unless you change it to a data frame.

Comment: Thanks! Refer to warning message 4,  `AirPassengers$year <- as.numeric(rownames(AirPassengers))`. I just added `AirPassengers <- readRDS("AirPassengers.Rds")` before this line and it solved now.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to warning message 4,
`AirPassengers$year <- as.numeric(rownames(AirPassengers))`. I just added `AirPassengers <- readRDS("AirPassengers.Rds")` before this line and it solved now.